# UIAutomation cannot access element

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I have a UIAutomation script where I need to select a button of a `UISegmentedControl` that is inside a custom view. This custom view is the header view of a `UITableView`

I tried both of those calls but they don't work

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().segmentedControls()[0].buttons()["Stats"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().segmentedControls()["mySegmentedControl"].buttons()["Stats"].tap();
```

I get the error "Cannot perform action on invalid element" which means that the `UISegmentedControl` wasn't found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this a bit ago. Do you have 'isAccessibilityElement' set to true on your custom view? If you do, that might be your issue, if it's set to true, it 'hides' accessibility to the children of that view, which means you wouldn't be able to access your button.

Comment: No, I did not set anything programatically nor in the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" of main custom view. I just set the `accessibilityIdentifier` on the segmented control on the xib

Comment: I also tried overriding the `isAccessibilityElement` to `NO` in my container view but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to set a `accessibilityIdentifier` on the custom view and on the contained `UISegmentedControl` and then use

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].groups()["MyCustomView"].segmentedControls()["MySegmentedControl"].buttons()["Stats"].tap();
```